# How can I view the EXIF orientation of a photo in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photos, exif

I have a photo and I want to determine whether the EXIF tags specify a rotation/orientation (portrait/landscape) or not.

Can I do this in Photoshop (CC v14)?  I just can't seem to find any reference to rotation or orientation under *File > File info...*  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

When you go to File > File Info, select Raw Data.

The data will be available under Orientation as a number.

From the available information [online](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html), these numbers represent the following:

- 1 = Horizontal (normal)
- 2 = Mirror horizontal
- 3 = Rotate 180
- 4 = Mirror vertical
- 5 = Mirror horizontal and rotate 270 CW
- 6 = Rotate 90 CW
- 7 = Mirror horizontal and rotate 90 CW
- 8 = Rotate 270 CW